# Power Bi Dashboard integration with Power Portal 9.5.5.x

Tags: powerbi, liquid, portal

I am trying to integrate Power Bi dashboard with Power Portal without using Power Bi Component. Followed the instructions provided in MSDN which displays a blank page.

Greatly appreciated any suggestions.

Tried following the instructions provided in MSDN documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-apps/maker/portals/admin/add-powerbi-report